# How to leave a textbox when clicked somewhere else?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

Right now, this is the program I use for enter/leave:

```
    private void tbFullName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbFullName.Text == "Full name")
        {
            tbFullName.Text = "";
            tbFullName.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void tbFullName_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbFullName.Text == "")
        {
            tbFullName.Text = "Full name";
            tbFullName.ForeColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
        }
    }
```

It only leaves when I focus on another element. I want it to leave when I click on the background, or anywhere else. How can I do that?

Comment: By the way, this is just an example for watermark I use. There might be other situations.

Comment: That functionality is built in to Windows.  Research Cue Banner

Comment: you should do it by control focus, like when click on background set ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Enter and Leave events of `TextBox`, use `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events, secondly to leave from the textbox use Form's Click event to call the LostFocus event. but before calling it Disable the textbox and after calling Enable the textbox like below code

In forms initialize event

```
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //attach the events here
        tbFullName.GotFocus += TbFullName_GotFocus;
        tbFullName.LostFocus += TbFullName_LostFocus;
    }
```

TextBox Events like this

```
    private void TbFullName_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbFullName.Text == "")
        {
            tbFullName.Text = "Full name";
            tbFullName.ForeColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
        }
    }

    private void TbFullName_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbFullName.Text == "Full name")
        {
            tbFullName.Text = "";
            tbFullName.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

Finally, Form's Click Event as

```
    private void Form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbFullName.Enabled = false;       //disable the textbox
        TbFullName_LostFocus(sender, e);  //call lost focus event
        tbFullName.Enabled = true;        //enable the textbox
    }
```

This workaround may help you.

Comment: It really helped me. Thanks for taking your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the answers this question already has. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).